# Flatten different properties into single array

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have a javascript object literal as follows.

```
    data: {
       prop1ByZones:[{zone: "Zone1", x: 1}, {zone: "Zone2", x: 5}],
       prop2ByZones:[{zone: "Zone1", y: "1302.5"}],
       prop3ByZones:[{zone: "Zone2", z: 2}]
    }
```

the output should be like -

```
output: [{zone: "Zone1", x: 1, y: "1302.5", z: 0}, {zone: "Zone2", x: 5, y: 0, z: 2}]
```

I can do it in trivial way like first add prop1ByZones to output and then loop through prop2ByZones and prop3ByZones and check for existing zone. if the zone is there then update it else add it.

I just wanted to check if there is any elegant way of doing it. Please let me know.

Comment: You might consider looping over the values of *data* and concatenating the various arrays. Where's your attempt? Something like  `Object.values(data).reduce((acc, arr) => acc.concat(arr), [])`.

Answer (score 0):

One possible approach:

```js
var data = { prop1ByZones:[{zone: "Zone1", x: 1}, {zone: "Zone2", x: 5}], prop2ByZones:[{zone: "Zone1", y: "1302.5"}], prop3ByZones: [{zone: "Zone2", z: 2}] }

var arr = [...data.prop1ByZones, ...data.prop2ByZones, ...data.prop3ByZones]
var resp = arr.reduce((acc, { zone, x, y, z }) => {
  var prev = acc.find(x => zone == x.zone);
  if(prev) {
    prev.x = x ? x : prev.x,
    prev.y = y ? y : prev.y,
    prev.z = z ? z : prev.z
    return acc;
  }
  return acc.concat({zone: zone, x: x ? x : 0, y: y ? y : 0, z: z ? z : 0});
}, []);

console.log(resp)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way to do this (using lodash for iterating), you could optimize the conditionals a bit to be ternaries etc, but this would give you your output:

```
const data = {
       prop1ByZones:[{zone: "Zone1", x: 1}, {zone: "Zone2", x: 5}],
       prop2ByZones:[{zone: "Zone1", y: "1302.5"}],
       prop3ByZones:[{zone: "Zone2", z: 2}]

};

let list = {};
_.each(data, (d, i) => {
   _.each(d, (e) => {
     const zone = e.zone;

     if (!list[zone]) {
       list[zone] = zone;
       list[zone] = {};
     }

     if (!list[zone].x) {
        list[zone].x = e.x || 0;  
     }

     if (!list[zone].y) {
        list[zone].y = e.y || 0;  
     }

     if (!list[zone].z) {
        list[zone].z = e.z || 0;  
     }

   });

});
// put everything in an array
let result = [];
_.each(list, (obj, k) => {
  result.push({
    zone: k,
    x: obj.x,
    y: obj.y,
    z: obj.z
  });
});

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the [`Object.values()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values), flatten to a single array by [spreading](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) into [`Array.concat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat), and then [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) the array to a [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map), and spread the [`Map.values()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map/values) iterator back to array:

```js
const data = {
   prop1ByZones:[{zone: "Zone1", x: 1}, {zone: "Zone2", x: 5}],
   prop2ByZones:[{zone: "Zone1", y: "1302.5"}],
   prop3ByZones:[{zone: "Zone2", z: 2}]
}

const result = [... // spread the map values iterator (see end) back to an array
  [].concat(...Object.values(data)) // get the object's values and flatten to a single array
  .reduce( // reduce the array to a Map
    // add the zone key to the map, and include the previous and current item
    (r, o) => r.set(o.zone, { ...(r.get(o.zone) || {}), ...o }), 
    new Map()
  ).values()] // get the map values iterator
  
console.log(result)
```